# Prepend to a line in vi

Tags: vi

Simply, I want to do the opposite of `A` in vi — so where `A` puts you in insert mode and brings you to the end of the current line, I'm looking to go into insert mode at the *start* of the current line.

So, is there an equivalent to:

```
0
i
```

in one keystroke?

I'm sure this must have been asked before, but any search I do (here or Google) returns only results for much more complicated tasks.

It feels like it should be possible in such a powerful tool, but can't find it on cheatsheets, etc. for vi.

Comment: At the beginning of the _text_ on the line, you can use `I`. I've never seen anything that inserts before indentation, though, which is annoying.

Comment: Thanks @JohnC. That does work in 95% of cases alright, it's just annoying for the other few times :)

Answer (score 1):

There does not seem to be such a default alternative.

Except for `0i` you could also type `gI`.

If you per se want to have it in one keystroke, you can define a map

```
:map X gI
```

`X` being your character of choice.

Because this mapping will most like kill the default behavior of a certain key, you should be aware that it is a non-portable solution. Define it in your `.vimrc` to have the map in place by default.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>g</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>

Insert in the beginning of the line. Equivalent to <kbd>0</kbd> <kbd>i</kbd>

<kbd>I</kbd>

Insert before the first non-blank character of the line. Equivalent to <kbd>^</kbd> <kbd>i</kbd>